# Angular 2 can't call class function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular

inside my class I have a simple function that logs errors called `logError(error);`

I also use google maps api to grab latitude and longitude of an address, so all together this looks like this inside my exported class.

```
  //Log error
  logError(err) {
   console.error('Error: ' + err);
  }

  //Get Coordinates from address
  postcodeCoordinates(address: string, postcode: string) {
    var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address + ', ' + postcode}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
       this.logError("Error " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

The issue is that I get console error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logError' of undefined` , but this function works perfectly fine called in a same way from other places in the code, which makes me thing that `this` in `this.logError("Error " + status);` refferes to google maps api, instead of my class. How can I work around this? is there a way to achieve something like `MyClassName.logError("Error")` (Tried this, doesn't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an arrow function, the `this` keyword will the one for your component and not the one of the callback function. Something like that:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address + ', ' + postcode}, (results, status) => {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat() + " " +results[0].geometry.location.lng());
  } else {
   this.logError("Error " + status);
  }
});
```

In this case, `logError` is a method of your current class.

To give you more details, when using the `this` keyword in a function, it corresponds to the object the function is executed on:

```
// Example #1

function test() {
  console.log(this);
}

test(); // prints null

// Example #2

var obj2 = {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

obj2.test(); // prints obj2

// Example #3

var obj3 = {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

var fct3 = obj3.test;
fct3() // prints null!!

// Example #4

var obj4 = {
  test: function() {
    geocoder.geocode({ ... }, function(results, status) {
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
};

obj2.test(); // doesn't print obj2
```

When you provide a callback, it will be executed as a function outside any object as a context or with a specific context (and not the caller one). This means that inside your callback the `this` keyword corresponds to the context your callback is executed on and sure, it's not the component instance.

It's a common problem in JavaScript application. Arrow functions aren't classical functions and introduce the "lexical this" concept. This means that they don't use their own `this` but use the one from the caller:

```
var obj2 = {
  test: function() {
    geocoder.geocode({ ... }, (results, status) => {
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
};

obj2.test(); // prints obj2
```

This link could help you: https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/. See the section: "Functionality: lexical scoping this".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry