# How to throw event in Angular2 when signalR called the client

Tags: events, typescript, signalr, angular

In a SignalR-Service inside my angular2-Application I want to broadcast an event when I received an event from the server.

```
@Injectable() export class SignalRService {

   //...
    private emitMe: EventEmitter<any>;

constructor() {
        this.emitMe = new EventEmitter();
        this.connection = jQuery.hubConnection(".../signalr/");
        this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy("...");
        this.wireupEvents();
        //...
    }

wireupEvents(): void {
    this.proxy.on('ItemAdded', function(data) {
            console.log('received ItemAdded' + JSON.stringify(data));
                //How to throw event here??? Like $rootScope.$emit('itemAdded', data);
                // 'this.emitMe' is not reachable here
            });
    }
}
```

How can I access the EventEmitter which I initialized and throw an event that I can subscribe from the outside to it?

Thanks

Regards Tenoda

Comment: How did you manage to get **SignalR** hooked up with **Angular2**?

Comment: https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNET-Core-Angular2-SignalR-Typescript

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
constructor() {
  this.emitMe = new EventEmitter();
  //...
}

wireupEvents(): void {
  this.proxy.on('ItemAdded', (data) => {
    console.log('received ItemAdded' + JSON.stringify(data));
    let someObject = (...)
    this.emitMe.emit(someObject);
  });
}
```

Using arrow functions you can use the `this` keyword directly within callbacks. This answer could also help you: [Angular 2 can't call class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808369/angular-2-cant-call-class-function/34808391#34808391).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Just assign this to that and use it,

```
private emitMe: EventEmitter<any> =  new EventEmitter();

wireupEvents(): void {
    let that = this;
    this.proxy.on('ItemAdded', function(data) {
            console.log('received ItemAdded' + JSON.stringify(data));
            that.emitMe.emit(data);
     });
  }
```

Crazy right ;).
variable scope for `this` is not the `this` that you need so `this` don't have `emit` but by assigning `this` to `that` now we have `emit`